# How to compare the data in JSON object to a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

Hi guys so I was wondering if it was possible to search content in a Json object with a variable?

Example:

```
var username = "name";
```

The json object Im getting from an api is in the following format:

```
{"name":{"id":224463,"name":"name","profileIconId":715,"revisionDate":1465905397000}}
```

The username is obviously different for everyone. I want to be able to get the id of the user and display it when the user enters their username in a text field.

```
 HTTP.get(url,function(error,result){
    var username ="somename";
    console.log(result.username.id);

    });
```

That code above gives me undefined but if I put somename where username is then it works fine.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property using a variable

```
console.log(result[username].id)
//               -^-      -^-
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly

Comment: @user3521579 : glad to help you :)